# Magento 1.9.3.6- Performance Suddenly Decreased

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

```
Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
mage    25.4225 1   0   0
mage::dispatch::routers_match   25.3104 1   0   0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view   25.2373 1   0   0
frontend/default/sanorita/template/page/2columns-left.phtml 23.6426 1   8,290,952   8,912,896
frontend/default/sanorita/template/page/html/head.phtml 16.3933 1   489,488 524,288
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml  5.6521  1   5,057,944   5,505,024
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view   15.5733 
layout/db_update: MAP_popup 15.5236 1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_popup    15.5220 1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_uk_popup 15.5203 1   0   0
layout/db_update: product_list  15.5186 1   0   0
layout/db_update: catalog_category_default  15.5169 1   0   0
layout/db_update: CATEGORY_55   15.5153 1   0   0
layout/db_update: customer_logged_out   15.5133 1   0   0
layout/db_update: nitrogento_disable_reports_product_display_v14    15.5118 1   0   0
DISPATCH EVENT:controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before 0.0011  1
```

Answer (score 0):

@rakesh, Seems that you have issues on your `head.phtml` and the `page/2columns-left.phtml`. I suggest that you use the [AOE Profiler](https://github.com/reillo/Aoe_Profiler) to see which child blocks cause the performance issue.

Comment: ok but if you check this one layout/db_update: MAP_popup 15.5236 1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_popup    15.5220 1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_uk_popup 15.5203 1   0   0
layout/db_update: product_list  15.5186 1   0   0
layout/db_update: catalog_category_default  15.5169 1   0  

it will take so long time 

how to resolve it ?